# PHP class for Aztec 2D Codes?

Tags: php, aztec-barcode

I've looked at Zint, and well c++ is way out of reach to me. I've also the extremely cool ZXing, but still Java is not quite there yet...

Just feel strange about not having any php ported version of these open source projects. I've read a few things about it being proprietary/patented... well it has been indeed released to public domain, and after all, it does have an ISO/IEC 24778:2008 so it does really look public domain...

Any thoughts about this guys?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also been looking for something similar to no avail; the closest (free) code that I've found is in Zend, which appears to have [a barcode generating class called Zend_Barcode](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.barcode.objects.html) that can be extended to support more formats.

The authors of the class are Mickael Perraud and Julien Pauli. Back in Oct. 2010 Mickael [replied to a question similar to this one](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=43220) ("Is the ability to render 2D barcodes in the future possible with the current implementation?") that 2D barcodes are "in progress but only for ZF2".  Zend is current at 1.11.3 and I'm not sure when Zend 2 is planned.

Mickael posted an early demo of the 2D functionality at http ://mikaelkael.fr/barcode/, but it looks pretty barren and hasn't been updated in a long while.  Perhaps if you contact him directly, via the Zend forums or even look at the SVN source he had posted at svn: //mikaelkael.dyndns.org/barcode.

Hope that helps someone, if not you :)

Comment: ... here's a [link](http://framework.zend.com/zf2) to the ZF2 docs however the only barcode mentions I've found are in the validation section, not for output.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently looking for a decent self-contained Aztec barcode generator for PHP and came across this question. As the topic is a few years old now, I thought I'd share what I found.

There is indeed a port of the ZXing code (the Aztec part of it anyway) on Github now under the name [Metzli](https://github.com/z38/metzli). As it is using namespaces, the PHP version required is >5.3

I hope this helps.